# Changing hue of rgba color

Tags: matplotlib, colors

I'm plotting a bunch of data on a logscale as a scatter plot in matplotlib (just in case the medium is relevant) using RGBA colors. What I would like to be able to do is once I plotted everything, I want to pick out individual scatter points and change their hue to the hue of some RGB color, but preserving the old alpha value. The way I currently do it is this:

```
oldHSV = rgb_to_hsv(oldRGBA[:3])
newHSV = rgb_to_hsv(newRGB)
oldHSV[0] = newHSV[0]
newRGBA = hsv_to_rgb(oldHSV).tolist() + [oldRGBA[3]]
```

i.e. I take the RGB part of the old RGBA value, turn it to HSV, do the same for the new intended RGB color, then replace the hue, turn it back to RGB and add on the old alpha value.

Since I'm doing this thousands of times, this can take significantly longer than I would like to spend here. One possible fix would be to dig into the conversion between RGB and HSV and figure out how to do this in one go, but I was hoping that folks who know how to handle color (I really don't) have figured out simple and efficient ways to do this.

How do I change the hue of a given RGBA color A to that of a given RGB color B while preserving the alpha value of A? Would using a different color model (HSL for example) simplify the task, and if so, which would help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution to do all the replacement in one go :

```
import matplotlib.colors as clr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 100000
x = 1.2 + 800.0 * np.random.rand(N)
y = 1.2 + 800.0 * np.random.rand(N)
# Generate random colors of the form (r, g, b, a) where r = 0.0
colors = np.random.rand(4 * N).reshape((N, 4))
colors[:, 0] = 0.0
area = np.pi * (5 * np.random.rand(N))**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
pcol = ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

# Save initial figure
plt.savefig("hue.jpg")

oldRGBA = pcol.get_facecolors().reshape((N, 1, 4))
oldRGB = oldRGBA[:, :, :3]
newRGB = oldRGB
newRGB[:, :, 0] = 1.0 # Set red component to 1.0
oldHSV = clr.rgb_to_hsv(oldRGB)
newHSV = clr.rgb_to_hsv(newRGB)
oldHSV[:, :, 0] = newHSV[:, :, 0]
newRGBA = np.copy(oldRGBA)
newRGBA[:, :, :3] = clr.rgb_to_hsv(oldHSV)
pcol.set_facecolors(newRGBA[:, 0, :])

# Save modified figure
plt.savefig("hue_bis.jpg")

plt.close()
```

As you can see, this code attempts to plot 100000 points and in fact it managed to do this in about 2 seconds. Here are the figures produced :

[image: hue.jpg]

and :

[image: hue_bis.jpg]

With regard to your last two questions :

> How do I change the hue of a given RGBA color A to that of a given RGB color B while preserving the alpha value of A ?

and :

> Would using a different color model (HSL for example) simplify the task, and if so, which would help

I think that your approach to do such a modification is appreciable, it avoids making calculations by hand (see [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)). Using a different color model is possible, both HSL and HSV allow to change the hue without affecting other parameters, but that is only an other way to do it and not a better one.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is interesting; while not leading to a way to improve the performance of my code, it gave me a perspective to see how other people's code would go about it (and that my code isn't slower).

Comment: Oh ! I expected better performance in one go. I will look at it a little closer. Do you have a working piece of code that implements your solution and allows myself to save time, please ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't; my code is in a data visualization tool, and I thought that changing the hue might be the bottleneck in one of the operations I apply to the visualization. I can't really extract it, it's not written elegantly enough for that. But actually, your answer basically answered my problem: is this actually a bottleneck and can I process stuff faster? Turns out, apparently not, so now I can go turn to other potential issues.

Comment: I understand. By the way, it could be interesting for a future reader to have a comparison point. Could you just give a estimation of the minimal number of points needed to reach a performance of about 2 seconds, please?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to extract the alpha from `oldRGBA` and apply it to `newRGB` directly:

```
newRGBA = colors.to_rgba(newRGB, alpha=oldRGBA[3])
```

Note: I never used matplotlib, I assume the alpha component is the 4th element of the color