# programatically modify a given matplotlib color (e.g. RGBA tuple) to vary brightness or hue

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I often am in a situation where I have a set of colors (lets say, `c = ['red', 'green', 'blue']`, but these may instead be RGBA specifications instead of strings) which I'm using to plot a corresponding set of parameters.  I then decide that I want to plot two variations of each parameter, so I'd like to end up with a 2x3 array of colors like `[['red', 'light-red'], ['blue', 'light-blue'], ['green', 'light-green']]`.  **Is there a way to programatically modify a given color (as a string or RGBA tuple) to be lighter/darker/hue'ier/saturated'er?**

Comment: It's easy if you use a numeric triple or quad, instead of a name, for each color. Can you do that?

Comment: @cphlewis I say in my question that that's also an easy option.

Comment: Then check out RGBA to HSV conversion, as in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074231/changing-hue-of-rgba-color . Changing hue and saturation will then be trivial.